# convert multiple '.alaw' files to '.mp3' in parallel

Tags: shell, multitasking, sox

```
/root/date/agent1/voicefilename-in.alaw
/root/date/agent1/voicefilename-out.alaw
/root/date/agent2/voicefilename-in.alaw
/root/date/agent2/voicefilename-out.alaw
/root/date/agent4/voicefilename-in.wav
/root/date/agent4/voicefilename-out.wav
```

i am using below script to convert above type files to mp3.

Its taking so much time to complete conversions because at a time it converting only one file

is there any other way to read and convert multiple files at a time

```
 FILES=/root/*/*/*-in.*"
  for f in $FILES
  do
    fileroot="${f%-in.*}"
    if [  ${f##*.} == "alaw" ]
    then
        sox -t al "$f" -s -r 8000 -2 "$fileroot"-in.wav
        sox -t al "$fileroot"-out.alaw -s -r 8000 -2 "$fileroot"-out.wav
        sox -m  "$fileroot"-in.wav "$fileroot"-out.wav "$fileroot".wav
        lame -q0 -b8  "$fileroot".wav  "$fileroot".mp3
        rm  "$f" "$fileroot"-out.alaw "$fileroot"-in.wav "$fileroot"-out.wav  "$fileroot".wav
    elif [  ${f##*.} == "wav" ]
    then
         sox -m  "$f" "$fileroot"-out.wav "$fileroot".wav
         lame -q0 -b8  "$fileroot".wav  "$fileroot".mp3
         rm "$f" "$fileroot"-out.wav "$fileroot".wav   
    fi
done
```

Comment: assuming you have a multi-core machine check out GNUparallel. There have been several Qs in the last 6 months where the answer used GNUparallel for tasks similar to your problem. You would create a script designed to process one file only (remove the `for` loop).  Good luck.

Comment: assuming the script that processes only one file at a time, you could also construct a pipeline like `find . -name '*.mp3' | xargs -n ${numberOFParlellProcs} /path/to/myConversionScript` . and get roughly the same result. There are enen more answers here for `xargs` that should be able to help you, or for both options, read their `man` pages. Good luck.

Comment: by using  find . -name '*.alaw' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -t -r -I {} sox -t al {} -s -r 8000 -2 {} i am able to convert multiple file at a time but  how to remove .alaw extnsion and append .wav to same file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *GNU* `parallel` to convert *.alaw* files using one process per CPU core, writing each output file to the current directory, try something like:

```
parallel sox {} {/.}.mp3 ::: /root/date/agent1/*.alaw
```

Then if the output is satisfactory, and the source files are no longer needed:

```
rm /root/date/agent1/*.alaw
```

Comment: More accurately, **GNU Parallel** defaults to one job at a time per *CPU core* than per CPU.

Comment: sorry parallel option is not avialble in my system.i am trying to user xargs find . -name '*.wav' -type f -print0 | xargs  -0 -t -r -I {} lame -q0 -b8  {}  {}.mp3.but its executing only one command at a time.please suggest any modifications in above command

Comment: Try using the `-P` option set to the number of CPU cores: `find . -name '*.wav' -type f -print0 | xargs -P$(nproc --all) -0 -t -r -I{} lame -q0 -b8 {} {}.mp3`.